# How to extract base name and append it to path

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

Basically, I want to transform `./foo/bar` to `./foo/bar/bar`.  I initially tried sed but the regex I came up with uses lookaround (`(?<=s\/)(.*)`) or the `\K` escape sequence (`.*\/\K.*`), which sed does not support.

Comment: For a single variable with that content? A file with many lines like this one?

Comment: @Benjamin W.    It's for the output of the find command:  find . -mindepth 2 -type d ! -path . ! -path ./foo

Comment: Even when will not talk about the missing piece of **your** code, the problem description is vague too. What should happen when the path will be one of the following?: `/` or  `.` or  `..` or `./..` and like? Or? `./qoo/qxx/../../../some/exotic/beauty/../`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the general case of "how do I append `/name` to `/path/to/name`", you can use parameter expansion:

```
$ var='./foo/bar'
$ echo "$var/${var##*/}"
./foo/bar/bar
```

`${var##*/}` expands to the value of `$var` with the longest possible match of `*/` (anything ending with a slash) removed from its beginning.

If you have a file with one of these entries per line, you could do something like this with sed:

```
$ cat infile
./foo/bar
./foo/bar/baz
./path/to/file
$ sed 's/\([^/]*\)$/\1\/\1/' infile
./foo/bar/bar
./foo/bar/baz/baz
./path/to/file/file
```

This captures everything after the last `/` on each line and appends a slash and the captured sequence to the end of the line.

Comment: Nothing beats good old *parameter expansion with substring removal*, good job.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin With the addition: _mostly_. :) This answer is nice and concise for the _most_ cases. Examples when will not DWIM: `/foo/bar/` , `/foo/bar//` (e.g. trailing slash(es)) and corner cases like `..` (aka parent directory, or `./..` or `./../` and such exotic _(but valid)_ paths.) So, yes - nice answer - but the: _nothing beats_.. isn't fully true. ;)